# Join objects in sub-array into one array - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Is there a one-liner to do the following

```
NSMutableArray *allpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSMutableArray *arr in self.points)
     [allpoints addObjectsFromArray:arr];
```

I have an array of arrays (`self.points`) and I am joining all of the objects in the subarrays into a single array.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSArray *array1 = @[ @"a", @"b", @"c" ];
NSArray *array2 = @[ @"d", @"e", @"f" ];
NSArray *array3 = @[ array1, array2 ];
NSArray * flattenedArray = [array3 valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
NSLog(@"flattenedArray: %@", flattenedArray);
```

Output:

flattenedArray: (
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f
)

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer; it'd be `allpoints = [self.points valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"]` to apply directly to the question (and add a `mutableCopy` if you really want that characteristic on `allPoints`).

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to add all objects in an array of arrays (e.g., every `NSMutableArray` in `self.points` to another array without iterating through.

However, you could add a category to `NSArray` to do exactly what you're doing now, and then call it with one line later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing the array and adding objects at the same time then there is an initializer for that.

```
NSMutableArray *allpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.points];
```

If you already have the mutable array defined and you want to just append objects to the end then you can use the following.

```
[allpoints addObjectsFromArray:self.points];
```

Comment: `self.points` is an array containing more arrays—OP wants to add the elements from these arrays, not the arrays themselves.

Comment: Ahh, well in that case then yeah he will have to iterate through them. I mean if it's something he's doing alot then maybe he can create a category on NSMutableArray but for most applications that would probably be a little overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this.

```
NSMutableArray *allpoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.points]
```

would give you an array of the arrays, but there is no single line solution. I'd suggest writing a category that will do this for you so you can easily reuse it.